# What does the animal empathy background special bonus apply to?

Tags: animal-companions, background, middle-earth-role-playing

The 56–60 background result “Empathy with a type of animal” on **CGT-2 — Background Options Table**  is a little bit obscurely worded. It says,

> Any maneuver on or with such an animal receives a special +25 bonus.

Does that mean +25 to things like training or commanding the animal; or +25 to all maneuvers done while you have the animal in your possession, like climbing, swimming, running, using items, etc.?

Comment: Why the down votes?  This question reads fine to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will apply to any maneuver done:

- Whilst on the animal that involves using the animal or controlling it (i.e. riding and possibly herding)
- Any manuever that interacts the animal, i.e.  (See section 2.33 p.13 for a list of secondary skills)  i.e. only herding from the existing list of animal skills.

There may be other unlisted secondary skills that your GM (e.g. Train animal) may allow; see Rolemaster Character Law for examples of such skills as MERP is a simpler version of Rolemaster.

It's not going to apply to every manuever if, say, you had a pet lizard and had "Empathy with a type of animal: Lizard" and kept the lizard in your pocket all the time - that's just not in the essence of the background option or in the way that any other skill or background option works.